# How to use google maps node api using async await

Tags: node.js, google-maps-api-3, async-await

```
The following is example taken from the Google Maps node module

function doSomeGeoCode() {

  const googleMapsClient = require('@google/maps').createClient({
    key: 'your API key here',
    Promise: Promise
  });

  googleMapsClient.geocode({address: '1600 Amphitheatre Parkway, Mountain 
   View, CA'})
  .asPromise()
  .then((response) => {
    console.log(response.json.results);
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
  });
}
```

How do I call the doSomeGeoCode using async and await.  Also I need to invoke another function once I have received the response. Please suggest

Answer (score 9):

You just need to return promisified `googleMapsClient` and create another method to wait for the response, such as:

```
function doSomeGeoCode() {
  const googleMapsClient = require('@google/maps').createClient({
    key: 'your API key here',
    Promise: Promise,
  });

  // Return the promise
  return googleMapsClient.geocode({
      address: '1600 Amphitheater Parkway, Mountain View,CA ',
    })
    .asPromise();
}

async function myTest() {
  try {
    // Called the method which returns promise.
    // `await` will wait to get promise resolved.
    const result = await doSomeGeoCode();
    console.log(result);
  } catch (error) {
    // If promise got rejected.
    console.log(error);
  }
}

myTest();
```